# Proper Way to Copy a Complex Derived Type in Fortran

Tags: pointers, memory-leaks, fortran

I'm using Intel Visual Fortran 2015 with Visual Studio 2012.

I've tried many different ways to try to create a copy of one of my complicated derived types in my code and every way I can think to do it causes a memory leak, so I must be doing something wrong.

Here is a simplified example of my problem

```
type Vehicle_T

    real :: time
    real, dimension(3) :: eciPos
    ...
    a bunch of variables
    ...

end Type Vehicle_T

type, extends(Vehicle_Entity_T) :: Aircraft_T
    real :: alt
    ...
    a bunch of variables
    ...
end type Aircraft_T


type Track_T
    real :: tupdated
    ...
    a bunch of variables
    ...

    class(Vehicle_T), pointer :: object

end type Track_T

type(Track_T) :: a, b

a = constructTrack(various values)

b = copyTrack(a)

contains

!The simplest way I've found that works but causes memory leak
function copyTrack(inTrack) result(outTrack)

    type(Track_T), intent(in) :: inTrack
    type(Track_T) :: outTrack

    outTrack = inTrack
    allocate(outTrack%object, source = inTrack%object)

end function copyTrack

!Another method that causes a memory leak
function copyTrack2(inTrack) result(outTrack)

    type(Track_T), intent(in) :: inTrack
    type(Track_T) :: outTrack

    outTrack%tupdated = inTrack%tupdated
    ...copy all of the rest of the values...

    if(associated(outTrack%object)) deallocate(outTrack%object)
    allocate(outTrack%object, source = inTrack%object)

end function copyTrack2
```

Comment: I do not, (the second answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291814/memory-leakage-issue-in-fortran-when-allocating-an-array-inside-a-subroutine-and) however, I have tried nullify as well and it still leaves a memory leak.

Comment: Actually, I see an issue with this method. I was wrong in saying this worked. I'll fix the original post. What I was doing wrong just then was that I was deallocating the input object and then trying to copy that object into the output one.

Comment: The `deallocate(outTrack%object)` disassociates `outTrack%object` but also deallocates its original target `inTrack%object`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I see that now, but that isn't the main issue.

Comment: How are you testing for memory leaking?  Because of the `allocate(outTrack%object...)` when that pointer is already associated some tools may think there is a leak, when the target is still accessible through `inTrack%object`.

Comment: I'm running a loop that runs b = copyTrack(a) over and over again, and I run out of memory. Running out of memory doesn't occur (yet at least) in my real code.

Comment: A problem in `copyTrack2`: unless you have default initialization for `%object` (is that `%obj`?) then the component of an object is initially of undefined association status.  Then `if(associated(outTrack%object))` is not allowed.  [I'd probably better stop speculating after this...]

Comment: no, obj/object was just a typo sorry. Fixed. as for initializing object, as far as I am aware it is initialized properly. My code runs, and calculates things properly. This method of copying a derived type just seems to be causing memory issues.

Comment: This code cannot be compiled. The error can be *anywhere* in your real code. Please prepare a [mcve].

Comment: If it was a hard work, I wouldn't complain, but creating the MCVE took me less than 5 minutes and I have to familiarize with the code first...

Comment: No, it cannot be anywhere in my code because I isolated the problem, and I know that it is taking place with the code I showed you. There is no need to have a working example to answer this, honestly there shouldn't be a need for an example to get an answer to this, but I thought I would try to give some more clear context. This is a question on the proper way to copy data in Fortran without causing memory leakage, not me asking you to find out where my memory leak is. This method of asking a question is common and acceptable in every other programming language on SO except Fortran.

Comment: Because it strongly helps answering. I had to construct the working example anyway. Maybe some clever programmers in other languages can create such examples in their head, but in Fortran we are mostly non-CS majors. I am not such a good programmer to see everything in pseudocode. End the working code is even shorter (I was mainly just deleting and just added some initialization).

Comment: Why is the object component a pointer?  If the thing associated with that pointer component is being copied when an object of the derived type with that component is copied, that suggests that the derived type owns the object associated with the pointer, and use of a pointer component isn't consistent with that.  (Exceptions exist.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to take care of the `object` component `b` when you do

```
`b` = some_new_object
```

wherever that new object comes from. **Whatever you do in your function, it will always leak.** (Or not, if you use finalization, see below. I don't use it yet, because many compilers do not support it fully, mainly gfortran.)

The reason for the leak is that `b` contains a pointer component, which is accessible only from `b`. That the pointer will be overwritten during the intrinsic assignment and the target of the pointer will be lost.

**Use a subroutine:**

```
implicit none

type Vehicle_T

    real :: time = 0
    real, dimension(3) :: eciPos = 0


end Type Vehicle_T

type, extends(Vehicle_T) :: Aircraft_T
    real :: alt

end type Aircraft_T


type Track_T
    real :: tupdated

    class(Vehicle_T), pointer :: object => null()

end type Track_T

type(Track_T) :: a, b

integer :: i

allocate(Aircraft_T :: a%object)

do i = 1, 10
  call copyTrack(b, a)
end do

deallocate(a%object)
deallocate(b%object)

contains


subroutine copyTrack(outTrack, inTrack)

    type(Track_T), intent(in) :: inTrack
    type(Track_T) :: outTrack

    if (associated(outTrack%object)) deallocate(outTrack%object)
    outTrack = inTrack
    allocate(outTrack%object, source = inTrack%object)

end subroutine copyTrack



end
```

Or more nicely with overloaded assignment:

```
module types
  implicit none

  type Vehicle_T

      real :: time = 0
      real, dimension(3) :: eciPos = 0


  end Type Vehicle_T

  type, extends(Vehicle_T) :: Aircraft_T
      real :: alt

  end type Aircraft_T


  type Track_T
      real :: tupdated

      class(Vehicle_T), pointer :: object => null()
  contains
      procedure :: copyTrack
      generic :: assignment(=) => copyTrack
  end type Track_T

contains

    subroutine copyTrack(outTrack, inTrack)

        type(Track_T), intent(in) :: inTrack
        class(Track_T), intent(inout) :: outTrack

        if (associated(outTrack%object)) deallocate(outTrack%object)

        allocate(outTrack%object, source = inTrack%object)

    end subroutine copyTrack



end module


  use types

  implicit none

  type(Track_T) :: a, b

  integer :: i

  allocate(Aircraft_T :: a%object)

  do i = 1, 10
    b = a
  end do

  deallocate(a%object)
  deallocate(b%object)

end
```

With a function and finalization. *Hopefully* does not leak in ifort, but will leak in gfortran.

```
module types
  implicit none

  type Vehicle_T

      real :: time = 0
      real, dimension(3) :: eciPos = 0


  end Type Vehicle_T

  type, extends(Vehicle_T) :: Aircraft_T
      real :: alt

  end type Aircraft_T


  type Track_T
      real :: tupdated

      class(Vehicle_T), pointer :: object => null()
  contains
    final :: finalize_Track
  end type Track_T

contains

    function copyTrack(inTrack) result(outTrack)

        type(Track_T), intent(in) :: inTrack
        type(Track_T) :: outTrack

        outTrack = inTrack
        allocate(outTrack%object, source = inTrack%object)

    end function copyTrack

   subroutine finalize_Track(t)
     type(Track_T), intent(inout) :: t
     if (associated(t%object)) deallocate(t%object)
   end subroutine
end module


  use types

  type(Track_T) :: a, b

  integer :: i

  allocate(Aircraft_T :: a%object)

  do i = 1, 10
    b = copyTrack(a)
  end do

  deallocate(a%object)
  deallocate(b%object)

end
```

Comment: Thank you. I had just a few minutes ago figured out that it was an issue with intent(out), and was working on implementing the fix. The assignment overload is snazzy. I appreciate it.

Comment: Can you explain (a little) more on why there will always be (without finalization) a leak on that assignment?

Comment: I haven't heard of finalization before, I'll have to take a look into because I'm not following what it does. Are the deallocations at the end necessary? I was under the impression that at the end of a program (or function) variables no longer in scope are automatically deallocated.

Comment: @francescalus The way I understand it (and I may be wrong), is that if you use "intent(out)" (or a function since the result is an implied "intent(out)") it is causing the variable to automatically be disassociated without being deallocated which in turn causes "associated(object)" to return .false.

Comment: No, the `deallocate`s are not necessary, but are necessary to get a clean output from memory leak debugging tools like `valgrind` because main program variables are implicitly `save` and are not finalized or deallocated.

Comment: @TheComposer First, `intent(out)` and a function result are not the same. Especially here. With a function you don't have any access to the left hand side. The function result is not!!! the left hand side variable. First, a temporary object is created for the function result and that one is then assigned to the left hand side. And during the assignment the pointer on the left hand side gets overwritten.

Comment: @TheComposer With a subroutine you are actually dealing with the actual left hand side variable. For a subroutine you are right, `intent(out)` would also be a problem, because you also cannot use the previous state of the left hand side, because it is either undefined, or re-initialized.

Comment: Cool. That makes sense @ the deallocate explanation. Thank you for clarifying the last bit, while I "knew" the information about functions I was not putting it together properly.

Comment: The most robust method (compiler support aside) is the combination of the second and third - defined assignment with finalization.  Worth noting that `ALLOCATE(..., SOURCE=xxx)` breaks things if defined assignment is also meant to be used by `xxx`